# Serialising and counting a list of values

Tags: serialization, haskell

I need to serialise a large list of values using a custom encoding function (which I have).  I've done this and it works, but I'd also like to have it count how many values are being serialised and written to disk whilst still using a relatively constant amount of memory (i.e. it shouldn't need to keep the entire input list around, as it gets *very* large).

Without the requirement of keeping a count, binary, cereal and blaze-builder all work (using the equivalent of `B.writeFile "foo" . runPut . mapM_ encodeValue`); but no matter what I try to do with any of these libraries it seems that the resulting ByteString gets kept around in memory until it is finished rather than starting to be written to disk as soon as a chunk is available (even when using [`toByteStringIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/blaze-builder/0.3.0.1/doc/html/Blaze-ByteString-Builder.html#v%3atoByteStringIO) from blaze-builder).

This is a minimal example demonstrating what I've been trying to do:

```
import Data.Binary
import Data.Binary.Put
import Control.Monad(foldM)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

main :: IO ()
main = do let ns = [1..10000000] :: [Int]
              (count,b) = runPutM $ foldM (\ c n -> c `seq` (put n >> return (c+1))) (0 :: Int) ns
          B.writeFile "testOut" b
          print count
```

When compiled and run with `+RTS -hy`, the result is an almost triangular graph dominated by ByteString values.

The only solution I've found so far (that I'm not a big fan of) is to do the looping (either directly or with `foldM`) in IO using `B.appendFile` rather than within Put or directly constructing a Builder value, which to me doesn't seem very elegant.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised that `toByteStringIO` doesn't work, hopefully someone more familiar with that library will provide an answer.

That being said, whenever I want to intermix stream processing with IO actions, I usually find iteratees to be the most elegant solution.  This is because they allow for precise control over how much data is processed and retained, and for combining the streaming aspects with other arbitrary IO actions.  There are [several](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iteratee) [iteratee](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/enumerator) [implementations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iterIO) on hackage; this example is with "iteratee" because it's the one I'm most familiar with.

```
import Data.Binary.Put
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal (defaultChunkSize)
import Data.Iteratee hiding (foldM)
import qualified Data.Iteratee as I

main :: IO ()
main = do 
  let ns = [1..80000000] :: [Int]
  iter <- enumPureNChunk ns (defaultChunkSize `div` 8)
                            (joinI $ serializer $ writer "testOut")
  count <- run iter
  print count

serializer = mapChunks ((:[]) . runPutM . foldM
   (\ !cnt n -> put n >> return (cnt+1)) 0)

writer fp = I.foldM
   (\ !cnt (len,ck) -> liftIO (B.appendFile fp ck) >> return (cnt+len))
   0
```

There are three parts to this.  `writer` is the "iteratee", i.e. a data consumer.  It writes each chunk of data as its received and keeps a running count of the length.  `serializer` is a stream transformer a.k.a. "enumeratee".  It takes an input chunk of type `[Int]` and serializes it to a stream with type `[(Int, B.ByteString)]` (number of elements, bytestring).  Finally `enumPureNChunk` is the "enumerator", which produces a stream, in this case from the input list.  It takes enough elements from the input to fill  a single lazy bytestring chunk (I'm on 64bit, divide by 4 for 32bit systems), and then writes them to disk so they can be GC'd.

Comment: Why 8192 as opposed to any other value?  And where can I find the definition and type of the `run` function, as I couldn't find it in iteratee?

Comment: Though I think your solution demonstrates the issue I was having with my own solutions: it doesn't seem to be possible to construct the `ByteString` and counting how many values there are at the same time; you seem to have to do it whilst writing to disk.

Comment: Oh, and there's one aspect in what you're doing that differs from what my original version does: if I understand your code, you're returning and printing the number of **bytes** saved to disk, rather than the number of **values**.  As such, it's wrong :(

Comment: @ivanm: 8192 was chosen arbitrarily, however with 4-byte ints it's pretty close to `bytestring`s `defaultChunkSize` (from Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal).  It may be better to use `div defaultChunkSize 4`

Comment: @ivanm: yes, it was recording the number of bytes.  If you're just using `Int`s, you could simply divide by `sizeOf (0::Int)`.  However, I've edited my code so it would work even if all the elements aren't necessarily the same size.

Comment: So... is the way that it works is that it creates more of a list of chunks and for starters only counts the number of items that went into each chunk, thus reducing the overall memory usage (whilst still making the output from -hy rather spikey)?  Anyway, this works so I'll accept it as an answer (though I'm not sure if I'll go with this rather than looping in IO, since it seems that that's what you end up doing in writer anyway; depends on performance difference).

Comment: @ivanm: that's how it works.  I think the -hy output spikes have to do with the behavior of `appendFile`.  You're correct that it's basically looping in IO, but so is lazy I/O in the end.  Iteratees typically provide excellent performance, and they're much more composable than working directly in IO.